# How to set up an endpoint for Health check on Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, next.js

I have an application deployed on Kubernetes (Google cloud). For the deployment to function, it needs to return a 200 status response to "/healthz" and "/". I have this set up on my Express server as a route returning a response like so:

```
app.use('/healthz', ((_req, res) => {
      logGeneral.info("Health Status check called.");
      res.sendStatus(200);
    }));
```

But I don't know how to do the same for my frontend which is running on Next.js / React. Commands such as res.send are not supported.

Anyone know?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try with a simple page? homepage, login? As long as it's a working url returning 200 it should work.

Comment: I got it to work on the "/" and "/healthz" route, but this is not good, as clients access the "/" base route and it's weird to see a 200 status code appear instead of the site.

Comment: You do know that if your site works, it's a 200 HTTP code that is returned? If not you wouldn't be able to navigate ;)

Comment: Kubernetes demands that I have 2 endpoints created which are dedicated to returning a 200 signal. I did this for the express server with the code I showed in the original post. But for Next.js I had to create 2 pages, one index and one Healthz just so I could return a 200 signal on each. Without this, it doesn't work.

Am I missing something here, I'm confused haha.

Comment: Health status pages are for readiness and liveliness probe, one of the two is only active at the start of the pod, liveliness pod is here to make sure that your app is still responding and in the case it isn't the pod will be restarted. In cas you can code those pages, you can give any path you want to those checks, but in some cases, you can't. Some apps don't come with custom path available and in those case any necessary page can be used to assume that it is up.

Answer (score 28):

Using an API route is the correct answer. Create a new file in /pages/api called healthcheck.js with this content:

```
export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ "status": "ok" })
}
```

The endpoint will be at (hostname)/api/healthcheck

Comment: If I got it correctly we don't need to have a route using the frontend, it has to be from the API? Makes sense since if the API is not functional what are the clients gonna do with the frontend?

Answer (score 14):

If you have to use the root path of `/healthz`, you can add an API route as others here suggested;

```
// ./pages/api/health.js
export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.send('OK');
}
```

And additionally you define a rewrite in `next.config.js`, so `/healthz` will be handled internally by `/api/health`;

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
module.exports = {
  rewrites: async () => {
    return [
      {
        source: '/healthz',
        destination: '/api/health',
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

Comment: Do you have idea how to implement same in react app? Use a route created in react but it points to an api endpoint?

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar requirement. I had to deploy my code on AWS and I needed a health check URL something like http://localhost:4000/ping

I created one file called ping/index.js inside pages with following content-

```
// health check URL
function Ping() {
}

// This gets called on every request
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  context.res.end('pong');
  return { props: { } }
}

export default Ping;
```

[image]

References-

1. https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/6750
2. https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering

Comment: API resolved without sending a response for /api/health, this may result in stalled requests. Receiving this

Answer (score 6):

With Next.js 13 app route you can add a health check endpoint like this:

`src/app/api/health/route.ts` (`/api/health`)
`src/app/healthz/route.ts` (`/healthz`)

```
export function GET() {
  return NextResponse.json({});
}
```

or if you need plain text

```
export function GET() {
  return new NextResponse('OK');
}
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/router-handlers

Answer (score 3):

Used api route in next.js, which seems a proper way of handling such cases

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @Koen. answer.

If your app is running with basePath eg. "/abc" and you want to **exclude** the `basePath` from the Health check URL eg. https://example.com/healthz

Then the following code with work within the k8/docker container.

```
// ./pages/api/health.js
export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Health Check Okay' })
}
```

And in `next.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
 rewrites: async () => {
  return [
   {
     source: '/healthz',
     destination: 'https://example.com/api/healthz', 
     //can write destination: http://localhost:<PORT>/api/healthz to make it ENV independent. 
     basePath: false
   },
  ];
 },
};
```

Reference : https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/rewrites

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend adding one additional piece to the [NextJS API routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) solution to help deal with caching behavior.

Using Next 14.0.2, I ran into an issue where heath check requests responded with a 308 status code instead of the expected 200. I was able to remove this behavior my making use of the `Cache-Control: no-cache` [header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control).

```js
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
 
type ResponseData = {
  message: string
}
 
export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<ResponseData>
) {
  res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store')
  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Health checked' })
}
```

I'll caution by saying that I am not a frontend expert. FWIW my use case requires me to [configure](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/basePath) `basePath` in my  `next.config.json` file. It's possible that these configurations are interacting with eachother to produce the unexpected 308 behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with a solution like this:

```
// in /pages/api/health.js
export default function handler(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('OK');
}
```

is that it doesn't exercise *enough* to know if the app is healthy.

It is common enough for our app to pass this healthcheck but the home page will still generate a 500 Internal Server Error due to some missing dependency or other issue.

Therefore I believe the proper solution for a NextJs/React type health check endpoint must involve more of the stack than a server API handler does.

Therefore I humbly propose my answer:

```
// in next.config.js
 rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/api/health',
        destination: '/'
      },
    ];
  }
```

This will **rewrite** (a redirect would give you a 3xx response which would *pass* the healthcheck even if the destination returns 5xx) the call to your homepage which will give you a lot more confidence your app is healthy.